# Set font for single word in title of UINavigationController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, nsattributedstring

I have a `UINavigationController` that is set with `prefersLargeTitles = true`

[image: example image]

I would like to set the title so that rather than

**Discogs | Search Box**

it reads

**Discogs** | Search Box

I cannot see how to set the text via attributed text however.

Is this possible? **I am building my view programmatically**.

I see a `navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes` property but as that only accepts key/value pairs I do not believe this can be used to apply this effect.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a clean solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255658/large-navigation-bar-text-with-multiple-colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For large title:**

You can create custom view (with title label) and set constraints to navigation bar:

```
customView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
customView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true

self.navigationItem.titleView = customView
```

---

**For regular title:**

You can set custom label to navigationItem's titleView :

```
let navLabel = UILabel()
let navTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Discogs", attributes:[
    NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17.0),
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black])

navTitle.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: " | Search Box", attributes:[
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
    NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0, weight: 
        UIFont.Weight.light)]))

navLabel.attributedText = navTitle
self.navigationItem.titleView = navLabel
```

---

**Source:**

[Dushyant Bansal's Medium Article](https://medium.com/@dushyant_db/swift-4-recipe-using-attributed-string-in-navigation-bar-title-39f08f5cdb81)

Comment: This is a good solution that answers the question. I would also suggest OP reads the encapsulation of changing font (via a `ChangableFont` protocol) given in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51443349/10623169. Think it compliments your succinct answer nicely.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I had tried this approach however it does not seem to work when `prefersLargeTitles` is `true`